# base for $\tau_2$

Tags: general-topology

Be $\tau_{1}$ and $\tau_{2}$ topologies over $\mathbb{N}$ defined by:

$\tau_{1}=\{\{m\in \mathbb{N}:m<n\}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{\mathbb{N}\}\}$ and $\tau_{2}=\{A\subseteq \mathbb{N}: 0\in A\}\cup \{\emptyset\}$.

How is the $B_1$ base? A $B_2$ base for $\tau_2$ I would kick $\tau_1$. Is that correct?

Comment: The topologies are bases for themselves. What do you mean by "kick $\tau_1$"?

Comment: What is the definition of a base? A base is a set of elements that, through the union, generates any element of its topology. So think a little bit. How do you generate voids and sets that have zero?

Comment: Just want to inform you in case you don't know, if you are satisfied with any of the answers to your previous questions, you may accept them by clicking the tick mark button next to them. This grants both the answerer and you reputation points. If you want clarification, feel free to comment below the answers and get in touch.

Comment: "kick $\tau_{1}$" means choose $\tau_{1}$ to be the basis of $\tau_2$.

Comment: $\tau_1$ is a basis but it is also a topology. So it is a basis that generates itself. It is NOT a basis of $\tau_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Both $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ have the property that each point $n \in \Bbb N$ has a minimal open neighbourhood $O_n$ such that any open set $O$ that’s contains $n$ has $O_n$ as a subset.

For $\tau_1$ we take $O_n = \{m \in \Bbb N: m < n+1\}$ and for $\tau_2$ we take $O_n = \{0,n\}$. The minimality is easy to check.

So a (minimal) base for these topologies are $\{O_n: n \in \Bbb N\}$ in both cases.

Note that it equals $\tau_1\setminus \{\emptyset, \Bbb N\}$ in the first case, so that space only has 4 bases in total, which is quite rare.